# Can I get the request parameter at authentication time with spring security?

Tags: java, spring, web, jwt

I have developed a java spring server with security and JWT.
while developing, I got the question in the title because I should know the parameter value at authentication time.
Unless it, I should send JWT as the parameter.

Can I get the request parameter without affecting get parameters in the controller at the authentication time?

Exactly, I wanna compare the JWT payload and some data.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Spring Security is designed based on the standard Servlet Filter which is composed of a series of `FilterChain` for processing a HTTP request. Each filter in the chain is responsible for doing a particular thing such as authentication , authorization, session management, CSRF protection, exception handling etc...

Because of that , it means you can implement a Filter and play with the `HttpServletRequest` API to get the request parameter to validate JWT such as :

```
httpServletRequest.getHeader("xxxx");
httpServletRequest.getParameter("xxxxx");
```

Comment: I did use `httpServletRequest.getParameter("xxxxx");` in my code.
However, it makes error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response` in the controller. I want to don't affect my controller....

Comment: no idea why it says `getWriter()` as we only invoke the request related API which is read-only, no idea why it needs to deal with something related to "write" ...